# Can't load information for github.com

Tags: android, android-studio, github

I am trying to share my android studio project on Github but there is an error message in red as follows

[image]

I'm already logged in to Github but I have no idea why there is such an error. What does the error mean? and how do I solve it? I am kinda new to Github and Im sorry if this sounds stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Check first in Android Studio -> settings -> Version control -> GitHub: click the "`Test`" button and make sure it returns "`connection successful`"

Check also in command-line:

```
git config credential.helper
```

If you have a credential helper caching your credentials, it might cache the wrong ones.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because you have lost your personal access token.
You can fix this by going into your GitHub and then creating a new personal access token.
Go to your GitHub settings -> Developer Settings -> Personal access tokens Then generate a new token.
After generating a new token, you should then go back to your android studio, following settings -> Version control -> Github.
Odds are you were already signed in before, so first remove whatever account you had before.

[image]

After that, you click on the add and click on login with the token. From there, all you need to do is paste the access token you generated, and everything should work just fine from there.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check first in Android Studio -> settings -> Version control -> GitHub and select your account you already singed in and remove it by click to minus icon above your email
2. click to + icon and select log in with token ( now you need to get your github token )
3. go to [github](https://github.com/) and select Settings >> Developer settings >> Personal access token then generate new token and copy it
4. return to android studio and paste github token and press Add account